# IllegalStateException: No logcat header processed yet

Tags: android, ddmlib

with the new build-plugin 1.5.0 I sometimes get this error when running ui-tests:

```
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDOUT 05:22:33 D/ddms: Waiting for Monitor thread
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No logcat header processed yet, failed to parse line: --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.logcat.LogCatMessageParser.processLogLines(LogCatMessageParser.java:123)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.logcat.LogCatReceiverTask$LogCatOutputReceiver.processLogLines(LogCatReceiverTask.java:112)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.logcat.LogCatReceiverTask$LogCatOutputReceiver.processNewLines(LogCatReceiverTask.java:107)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.MultiLineReceiver.addOutput(MultiLineReceiver.java:100)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:519)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:382)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:353)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:604)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at com.android.ddmlib.logcat.LogCatReceiverTask.run(LogCatReceiverTask.java:75)
    2015-11-17 17:22:33 [SDR.printStream] [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] STDERR     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

anyone knows a workaround?

context: https://github.com/square/spoon/issues/302

Comment: check my comment under Spoon issue, somehow updating SDK fixed the problem

Comment: Updating the SDK doesn't work - thought so too, but now i have the same problem with the latest sdk. I posted also an bug at google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195998

Comment: I see these now, too. What gives? Stuff seams unrelated with what I'm struggling with and tests seam to run (currently fail) normally.